# Is it possible to find index of a class from a collection of elements with same class name using javascipt

Tags: javascript, foreach, click, addeventlistener, indexof

```
const bubbleBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

bubbleBtns.forEach( btn => 
    btn.addEventListener('click', btn => {
        console.log(btn.index);
    }));
```

This is the code snippet. Is there some method to get index of the specific element.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific element"? Are you able to make `'.btn'` more specific?

Comment: `.btn` is the class name for a number of `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forEach method has gives you the index in the second parameter of the callback function.

Also avoid giving the same name to different variables.

```
bubbleBtns.forEach((btn, index) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickedBtn => {
        console.log(index);
    });
});
```

Another option, if you need a specific order, is to use data- attributes. See this article about that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

In your case you could add data-index for the first element for example.

```
<element
    data-index="1"
/>
```

Then retrieve your given value like so:

```
bubbleBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickedBtn => {
        console.log(clickedBtn.dataset.index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad to help. Can you mark the answer as accepted please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
const bubbleBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

bubbleBtns.forEach(btn =>
    btn.addEventListener('click', getId));

function getId(event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bubbleBtns.length; i++) {
        if (bubbleBtns[i] == event.target) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```